# Sorting 2d-array in PHP by value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a code :

> $diagnose[$count][$row['result']];

I need to sort array by the value of [$count]

Comment: I think you're looking for `asort()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to sort the array by the **key value** (`$count`).

You should use `ksort()` (low to high) or `krsort()` (high to low). Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations.

Example:

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
```

In your case it should be:

```
ksort($diagnose);
```

To sort by **value** use `asort()`.

Find out more here sorting functions: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php